# How to restore my web application's old session when user re-opens the browser?

Tags: java, angular, hibernate, spring-mvc, angular5

I want my web application to continue from where it left off or to continue with its old session irrespective of the browser in which it is opened.

Main Technologies used for my application are java, spring, Hibernate and angular5.

I have done some research and it suggests me to use cookies to save session data.

Is using cookies the only way i can achieve it or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Sessions store the user data on the server. Cookies store user data on web-browser, which makes them less secure. However sessions expire when you close the browser. There is also `localStorage` - another client-side storage that uses cache to store the data. Cookies are primarily for server-side reading (can also be read on client-side), `localStorage` (and `sessionStorage`) can only be read on client-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have session data across multiple browsers (`irrespective of the browser in which it is opened`), a cookie and localStorage won't help you, since those are only related to one browser instance.

What you need would be to store all the data, that you want to have in your session, in your database in an appropriate data model, and then every time a user logs in, you fetch that data and add it to the current server session. Of course you also have to update the data if there are any updates.

E.g. for a shopping cart, like in Amazon, which is stored in your account and not in the cookie or browser, you would have a table `ShoppingCart` with a relation to the customer id, and then `CartItems` with a foreign key to the cart, and you would fetch the shopping cart for the customer which is currently logged in, to show all the items.

Comment: Thanks for your response dunni, but if user logins to application and then closes the browser and restart again then i want that same session to continue i.e user should be logged in to application. Will storing data into database work for this scenario?

Comment: No, for that obviously you need the cookie mechanism. So you need to distinguish in your case between the authorization session, which is always tied to the browser (e.g. with cookies) and has to be recreated if you use another browser, and data that should be available if you have different authorization sessions for the user (like the shopping cart).